# Grabbing public statuses through Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Life events on FB are public. Is there a way to get a list of recent life events for all users who have published a life event, not just current friends?

Edit:

Learned that there's no API for life events. Is there a way to get public statuses through a search for a keyword (with the exception of hashtags)?

Comment: Pretty sure that there is no API for life events.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for searching is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0#search

But keep in mind that the API v1.0 will be discontinued on april 30th 2015, then the search for public posts will not be availabe anymore.